# Why was Morgan/Ares pressurizing to negotiate peace?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

In *Wonder Woman*, when Trevor and Diana enters the assembly hall, we hear following dialogues from Sir Patrick Morgan AKA Ares.

> Germany is an immensely proud nation. They will never surrender. Now look. The only way to end this war... Colonel, I need to talk to you outside. ...and restore world peace... is to negotiate......an armistice.
>
> Our only aim at this time...... must be to achieve peace......at any cost!

<sub>[Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=wonder-woman-2017)</sub>

It is clear here that he wants to negotiate peace. However, he turns out to be Ares, a god of war who wants to continue an endless war.

**So why is he pressurizing on negotiating peace if he wants to continue the war?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because his plan was humanity eradication only. He said it himself:

> "When you first arrived, I was going to crush you, but I knew that if only you could see what the other gods could not, then you would join me and with our powers combined we could finally end all the pain, all the suffering, the destruction they bring and we could return this world to the paradise it was before them." [source](http://dcextendeduniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ares)

And that he was achieving with his poison gas plan, He did make one party agree to try for peace but manipulated other to kill. This will be more devastating when you try to have peace and get attack from unstoppable poison gas. It will leave a scar which will only fire the hate.

He was just being a double agent and making them fight each other but portraying himself as peacekeeper so they believe him and act like his pawns.

Answer (score 2):

> So why is he pressurizing on negotiating peace if he wants to continue the war?

## Because an armistice is not a surrender

An armistice is only an agreement to *stop fighting* while peace is negotiated.

> An armistice is a formal agreement of warring parties to *stop fighting*. **It is not necessarily the end of a war**, since it may constitute only a cessation of hostilities while an attempt is made to negotiate a lasting peace.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice)</sup>

A surrender would be an entirely different thing. The Germans would essentially be under the authority of the "winning" side.

Ares **knows** than an armistice *will not hold* (partially due to his own influence) and so the war would continue.

> ```
>           ARES 
>   All I do is orchestrate an
>   armistice I know they will break,
>   in the hope they will destroy
>   themselves.
> ```
>
> <sup>[Source](https://ricgibbs.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Wonder-Woman_Allan-Heinberg_2017.pdf)</sup>

His strategy is to work from the inside to destroy anything that would **end** the war which a *surrender* would actually do.